# Issue With a Simple Server - Client Program

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I run the following script:

```
import socket, threading, time,Queue
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

print("Starting...")

def server(): 
    s = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 1247
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection accepted from " + repr(addr[1]))
        c.send("Server approved connection\n")
        print (addr[1]) + ": " + c.recv(1026)
        c.close()

def client ():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Client Started")
    s = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 1247
    s.connect((host, port))
    print (s.recv(1024))
    inpt = raw_input('type anything and click enter... ')
    s.send(inpt)
    print ("the message has been sent")

q = Queue.Queue() 
t = threading.Thread(client(), args = (q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()  

server()
```

I get this error:

```
Starting...
Client Started
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Note that port 1247 is open in my device (Ubuntu OS).

Connection Refused means there is nothing to connect to. But What is wrong with the server, I cannot find the problem with it. Any help is very much appreciated after one week of tries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the thread, you are accidentally starting the client. The first argument of `threading.Thread` is `client()`, which executes the client including the initial `sleep`. Which blocks the main thread. You should change this to

```
t = threading.Thread(target=client, args = (q,))
```

The target argument expects a callable object, i.e. your client. Once you start the tread, it will execute the client on a different thread. Please note, the lack of `()` after `client`.

Comment: TypeError: client() argument after * must be an iterable, not instance

Comment: Also, I tried to run the server alone and try to `telnet` it from CLI but connection refused: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: And what is the difference between `client()` and `target = client` please?

Comment: The difference is the key here: `client()` will execute the function immediately, `target=client` passes the function as a callable object to the thread, such that the thread can call it later.

Comment: Additionally, a comma has to be added, such that `(q, )` is a tuple. I would also recommend to add `print("Listening on %s" % host)`.

Comment: It works by doing the following: `t1 = Thread(target = server)   
#t2 = Thread(target = client)

t1.start()

#t2.start()`